# Unable to launch Chrome browser using selenium using mac

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium and tried to hit simple chrome browser using selenium and by creating maven project in intellij, even i have aded the required dependencies to the pom.xml and provided setProperty().But still it is giving me an error chrome is getting launched but url is not getting hit.

Below are the dependencies i have added.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumBrowserConn1 {
public static void main(String args[]){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Chickoo/sDrivers/chromeSeleniumDriver/chromedriver");
        WebDriver obj1=new ChromeDriver();
        obj1.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }
}
```

Error:

> [warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to
>   localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28859 Build info: version: '3.11.0',
>   revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z' System info:
>   host: 'Bhavins-MacBook-Air.local', ip:
>   'fe80:0:0:0:102e:4c39:5e6a:6908%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
>   'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_161

Comment: Below is the error
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28859
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'Bhavins-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:102e:4c39:5e6a:6908%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_161'

Comment: Instead of a comment update the error stack trace within the question area.

Comment: Try with absolute path. 

example:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/naveen/Documents/Chickoo/sDrivers/chromeSeleniumDriver/chromedriver");`